# I don't know how to use POST method in sequelize (Mac)

Tags: javascript, mysql, post, sequelize.js, postman

I'm a student who want to learn about javascript, and not really good at English..
As i told you before, I tried to make editable mypage(profile).
I used mysql and sequelize and I did get method to make mypage but cannot use post method which
user can approach to their information (editting).
I want to use only nickname, birthday, phone, intro part
and if i use postman, blow the picture,
SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 113
come out..
Here is my models of Mentor(user) models.

```js
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Mentors', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    mentor_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    nickname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    sex: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    birthday: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    certification_path: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    intro: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'Mentors',
    timestamps: false,
  });
};
```

and here is mypage of mentors(user) which is I wanna fix POST part of it.

```js
const db = require('../../../models');

const { Mentors } = db;

module.exports = {
    get: (req, res) => {
        if (req.params.id) {
            Mentors
            .findOne({
                where: {
                    id: req.params.id,
                },
            })
            .then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    res.status(200).json(result);
                } else {
                    res.status(409).send('Wrong Access');
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            });
        }
    },
    post: (req, res) => {
        Mentors
        .findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.params.id,
            },
        })
        .then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                res.status(200).json(result);
            } else {
                res.status(409).send('Wrong Access');
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send(err); // help me...
        });
    },
};
```

and here is my postman for testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkymW.png)

plz help me guys~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off,  I think you need to need to solidify your knowledge of HTTP methods. [Here is a link](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html#:%7E:text=The%20primary%20or%20most%2Dcommonly,or%20CRUD) to help you understand it in the most basic way.

That said, naturally I would expect that you want to *create* a mentor in your POST. The code below looks like what you might plan to do in your `post` method.

```js
const post = (req, res) => {
        Mentors
        .findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.params.id,
            },
        })
        .then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                res.status(400).json({
                  error: true,
                  message: 'mentor account already exists',
                });
            } else {
                //Get your request body from req.body
                Mentor.create({
                  nickname: req.body.nickname //the name given to it on the frontend
                  // include the other fields you need to create the mentor
                }).then((mentor) => res.json({ error: false, data: mentor })
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send(err); // help me...
        });
    }
```

I'd also strongly recommend you learn to use ES6 async/await. It makes your code easier to read (even for you).

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, i'll read your url link. thanks for helping me